# Почему выводятся все варианты, а не только нужные?

Tags: python

Задача заключается в том, что нужно вывести варианты символов в строке. Если в данной строке есть пробелы их нужно убрать
Мой код:

```
import itertools
s = input()
new_s = ''
for x in s:
    if x != ' ':
        new_s += x
for j in range(len(new_s)):
    for i in itertools.permutations(new_s,j+1):
        print(''.join(i))
```

Но есть проблема в одном тесте
Если я ввожу `aaa`, то должно выводиться:

```
a
aa
aaa
```

А у меня выводит все варианты, то есть `a a a aa aa` и так далее.
Что нужно изменить в скрипте, чтобы он заработал корректно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во первых можно не сразу выводить, а накапливать результаты, например в множестве:

```
res=set()

for x in s:
    if x != ' ':
        new_s += x
for j in range(len(new_s)):
    for i in itertools.permutations(new_s,j+1):
        res.add(''.join(i))

print(*res)
```

P.S.

кстати от пробелов можно было и через replace избавиться

```
s = s.replace(' ', '')
```

P.P.S.

весь код можно записать так:

```
new_s = s.replace(' ', '')
for j in range(len(new_s)):
    print(*sorted(set(map(''.join, itertools.permutations(new_s, j + 1)))))
```

я добавил еще сортировку результата чтоб в лексическом порядке выводилось

Comment: Спасибо, все тесты прошли!

Comment: @akimochev У вас не принят ни один ответ к вашим вопросам. Не забывайте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer